Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Error Messages : NOT_REGISTER , Expo React Native
I've encounter issue in Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications Error Messages says : NOT_REGISTER
I am using Expo React Native this is the dependency i use
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.18",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.36.0",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "expo": "~51.0.17",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.19",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-document-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.6",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.9",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "firebase": "^10.12.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}


How i got this issue
I am always using apk build to test notifications since i got a problem with my android devices to connect to my laptop also i run a command of prebuild my app
i try a lot of method to fix it , it was works just for a couple time but it will get back to NOT_REGISTER error
the first thing is to clear the tables with fcm token in it , it's working for just couple updates i need to reinstall applications again and again since i can't use my usb for testing so i deploy it and build apk again.
i know the fact that applications that's uninstalled will got that error NOT_REGISTERED, i am trying to send a notifications to multiple user also the user such as JOHN maybe have 2 devices or more
and try to adding tools:node="replace" but how to do that since my prebuild AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="merge"
    tools:replace="android:label,android:allowBackup"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
      android:value="default"
      tools:replace="android:value" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color"
      tools:replace="android:resource" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.notifications.default_notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.notifications.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED"
      android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH"
      android:value="ALWAYS" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS"
      android:value="0" />
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
      android:exported="true"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.andarumobilebusinesspartner" />
        <data android:scheme="com.andarumobilebusinesspartner" />
        <data android:scheme="exp+andaru-business-partner" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
      android:exported="false" />
  </application>
</manifest>

Handling FCM Token

Fetch The Token from my expo react native and ask for permission

const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
    const [fcmToken, setFcmToken] = useState(null);
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState(undefined);
    const notificationListener = useRef();
    const responseListener = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
        // Register for push notifications
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
            .then(token => setExpoPushToken(token ?? ""))
            .catch(error => setExpoPushToken(`${error}`));

        // Set up notification listeners
        notificationListener.current =
            Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
                setNotification(notification);
            });

        responseListener.current =
            Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });

        // Check whether an initial notification is available
        messaging()
            .getInitialNotification()
            .then(async remoteMessage => {
                if (remoteMessage) {
                    console.log(
                        "Notification caused app to open from quit state:",
                        remoteMessage.notification
                    );
                }
            });

        // Handle notification opened from background state
        messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
            console.log(
                "Notification caused app to open from background state",
                remoteMessage.notification
            );
        });

        // Register background message handler
        messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log("Message handled in the background", remoteMessage);
        });

        // Handle new FCM messages
        const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
                content: {
                    title: "New FCM Message",
                    body: JSON.stringify(remoteMessage),
                },
                trigger: null,
            });
        });

        return () => {
            notificationListener.current &&
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
                    notificationListener.current
                );
            responseListener.current &&
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    const fetchFcmToken = async () => {
        const permission = await requestUserPermission();
        if (permission) {
            try {
                const token = await messaging().getToken();
                console.log("FCM token", token);
                setFcmToken(token);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error getting FCM token", error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Permission not granted for FCM");
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchFcmToken();
    });

and how i am handling the logout using useEffect in UserProvider Context that i wrapped in _layout.jsx
React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!user) {
            messaging().deleteToken();
        }
    }, [user]);

return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    );


I put the fcm token in my login function



const handleSubmit = async () => {
        const [username, domain] = email.split("@");

        const auth = {
            UserName: username,
            DomainName: domain,
        };

        const login = {
            password: password,
            applicationId: "AND_MOB_PAR",
        };

        if (email.includes("@") && password !== "") {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const res = await AuthServices.doLogin(auth, login, fcmToken);

                if (res) {
                    // Login successful
                    setToken(res);
                    setAuth(true);

                    const token = res;
                    const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
                    const apiURL = decoded.APIUrl;
                    const userId = decoded.UserId;

                    if (token) {
                        await localStore.string.post("key", token);
                        await localStore.string.post("apiURL", apiURL);
                        await localStore.string.post("userId", userId);

                        setUser(decoded);
                        const dataUser = await fetchDataUser(decoded);
                        setDataUser(dataUser);
                        if (dataUser) {
                            await localStore.object.post("dataUser", dataUser);
                        } else {
                            setDataUser(null);
                        }
                        handleNavigate();
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert("Error", `${error}`);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        } else {
            Alert.alert("Invalid Authentication");
        }
    };



please help me if you need me to show more details i will explain more
